# Unable to load google-translate script tag using pupeteer. How could I do this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to render a webpage at URL https://www.kent.co.in/ using the following statement with Puppeteer

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
const pageResponse = await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
```

It works just fine but there are few scripts that are not loaded. For example, as seen in the following screenshot the google-translate script is not loaded (while it gets loaded in the google-chrome desktop browser).

[image]

What I am trying here is to detect the URLs that use google translate. But for some reason, the particular google translate scripts are not loaded. What could be the reason for this? What is it that I am missing?

The only script tags that I am able to detect are:

```
[
 "https://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/ec.js",
 "//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js",
 "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js",
 "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-MZ5SGHP",
 "//bat.bing.com/bat.js",
 "//script.crazyegg.com/pages/scripts/0080/3537.js?438583",
 "https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js",
 "https://a.quora.com/qevents.js",
 "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-787579017",
 "https://www.kent.co.in/googleCssJs/jquery.1.12.4.min.js",
 "https://www.kent.co.in/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
 "https://www.kent.co.in/js/lazysizes.min.js"
]
```

and as could be seen it failed to detect the script tag with src set as `translate.googleapis.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wait enough for it. You can wait for a script tag with a particular src like this:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.kent.co.in/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
//scritps with src that starts with https://translate.google.com
await page.waitForSelector('script[src^="https://translate.google.com"]')
const scripts = await page.$$('script[src]');
for (let script of scripts)
    console.log(await page.evaluate(el => el.src, script));
```

Comment: Could I use a pattern with `waitForSelector`? For example, I just want to check for `translate.google.com` and not the complete URL